# Show that $x\in Bdry(A)$ if and only if $x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2=1$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Let $A$ be the set of points $x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$) such that $x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2\leq 1$. Show that $x\in Bdry(A)$ if and only if $x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2=1$.

---

Suppose that $x\in Bdry(A)$, then we have $x\in\bar{A}\bigcap\overline{C(A)}$, where $\bar{A}=A$ and $\overline{C(A)}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\;\vert\;x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2\geq1\}$. So, for $x\in R^n$, we have $x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2=1$. Conversely, suppose $x\in R^n$ satisfy $x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2=1$. Pick $\epsilon>0$, we have $B_\epsilon(x)$. Then, we have $B_\epsilon(x)\bigcap\bar{A}\neq\phi$ and $B_\epsilon(x)\bigcap\overline{C(A)}\neq\phi$. Hence, $\bar{A}\bigcap\overline{C(A)}\neq\phi$ and $x\in\bar{A}\bigcap\overline{C(A)}$. $x\in Bdry(A)$.

---

I don't think my attempt is right because I am still trying to understand Boundary, closure and interior. Any feedback could help.

Comment: Bdry = Boundary I presume? A standard (or atleast very common) notation for the boundary of a set $A$ is $\partial A$ (`\partial A`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first implication is correct.

For the second implication, you have to show that any ball around $x$ is not entirely contained in $A$. In other words it is enough to prove that $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap C(A) \neq \emptyset$.

It is enough to prove the statement above since such an $x$ is obviously in $\overline{A}$. Recalling that $\overline{A} = \text{int}(A) \cup \text{Bdry}(A)$, to prove that it is a boundary point we are left to show that $x \notin \text{int}(A)$.

Comment: for the second direction. As $x$ satisfy $x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2=1$, $x\in A\subset\bar{A}$ and $x\in\overline{C(A)}$, $x\in\bar{A}\bigcap\overline{C(A)}$. Can I do this?

Comment: @Simple: yes, that works :)